# How to add a new method to Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Could you please tell how to add a new method to Dojo?

It works for me, but only for *NodeList*:

```
dojo.extend(dojo.NodeList, {
    foo: function() {
        alert(1)
    }
});

dojo.byId("foo").foo();
```

But, i need for *Element*:

```
dojo.byId("id").myMethod();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dojo.byId` function is just an alias for `document.getElementById`. Therefore it returns a vanilla domNode, and what you suggest would be adding a new method to Element, not Dojo.

Dojo intentionally doesn't change Element, because it's considered bad practice to do so by some (it may collide with other frameworks, for example).

If you want to do it, you can add functions to Element's prototype:

```
Element.prototype.myMethod = function() { 
    alert("My content is: " + this.innerHTML);
};
```

Then you can do:

```
dojo.byId("id").myMethod();
```